# Azure Functions, Function key not accessible and files look missing in portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have deployed a javascript function app using VSTS Continuous Deployment and the function works but you can't see any of the code in the portal and the management screen looks seriously screwed up.  By Function state it only has a grayed out garbage can instead of the grayed out enable/disalbe and the function key section is completely missing.  The host keys section is empty even though I have host keys.  This is frustrating because I can't set any function keys.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc736892-a5eb-486a-8e25-6c0c711c2898/unable-to-start-deployed-functions?forum=AzureFunctions).

This probably means that your ARM template is incorrectly setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION. Please make sure to set it to ~1. See [this page](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/135) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If your host keys fail to appear after you have deleted and redeployed your function app (I had this issue after upgrade from ~2 to ~3) then ensure all file shares and blob-containers (in used storage account) with the function app name are also deleted before trying redeploy. specifically the following containers:
azure-webjobs-hosts
azure-webjobs-secrets

Only by clearing these was I able to get a clean re-deploy - and host/app keys back again!